# build.gradle changes for Android FCM

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, build.gradle, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to incorporate push notification in my Ionic app (on ionic 1.3.1) using plugin phonegap-plugin-push.

Once I add the Android app to Firebase it tells me to update the build.gradle files in two places.

[image]

I find two build.gradle files in my Ionic project (another one is part of another plugin so ignoring that)

```
./platforms/android/build.gradle
./platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
```

I have played with making changes in different files, put the first change in first file, second change in second one, but I am not sure what I am doing here as it gives compilation errors when I run `ionic build android`. All the articles I have come across in my research point to using Android Studio which I am not using. And I am not sure what to do with the `Synch now` as instructed by FireBase.

I have placed the google-services.json for android from Firebase under platforms/android in my directory structure which I understand is the right place.

Look forward to any guidance on which build.gradle change goes where and what, if anything, I need to do with "sync now" in the context of Ionic App and get this up and running.

Thanks,
Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

It make sense that two changes happen in two files. 
But for the app level one, you may write at the wrong one.
Please make sure you edit these two file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeD5L.png)

Comment: the image you have included is one from Android Studio. As I mention in my note above I am not using Android Studio. I have basic Ionic App (opened in Sublime) and the folder structure seems to be very different from the app created in Android Studio which is why I am not sure where the build.gradle changes that Firebase recommends need to go.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the recommendation in this article https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/83

I removed all changes to my build.gradle files as they are supposed to synch automatically and it compiles fine.

That said, I am using the phonegap-plugin-push plugin (instead of cordova-plugin-fcm as in the article above) and my app crashes after it tries to init PushNotification but that is a separate problem I need to handle.